# Series periodic by period 1 same as by 2?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is a series that is periodic by period 1 e.g. 2, 2, 2 etc also considered periodic by period 2?
Thanks

Comment: Clearly if $a_n=a_{n+1}$ we also have $a_n=a_{n+2}$.

Comment: Many times, we are *most interested* in the *least* length period (*if it exists*) and we call that its fundamental period.  [See wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_function).

Answer (score 2):

You probably mean a *sequence*, not a series.

If so, the answer is yes.

A sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is periodic with period $k\in\mathbb{N}$ if:
$$a_n = a_{n+k\cdot p}, \quad\forall n, p \in \mathbb{N}$$

Thus, if $a_n = a_{n+p}, \forall n, p\in\mathbb{N}$ then certainly $a_n = a_{n+2p}, \forall n, p\in\mathbb{N}$:

$$a_{n} = a_{n + p} = a_{(n + p) + p} = a_{n + 2p}$$

However, $1$ would be the *least period* of such a sequence.

Comment: @robjohn How is that possible?

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of functions not sequences. (I've already upvoted your answer)